# Visual Studio Placement of Closing Brace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Currently Visual Studio completes my if statement as the following:

```
if(true){
}
```

What I want is:

```
if(true){

}
```

I found a lot of options for placing opening brace on a new line under tools->options->text editor, but are there any options for the placement of closing braces? And it'd be great if my cursor ended up between the two braces.

Comment: I had a look and couldnt see anything either.. there were a few options under c# intellisense that did things with closing braces though

Comment: by the way, I believe Visual Assist X does what you want but thats not free...

Comment: @Sayse Fortunately I have visual assist and you were right! It was VAssistX -> Advanced -> Corrections. Thanks everyone for their inputs.

Comment: haha fair enough! I'll write it as an answer.. what would we do without va...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Assist has this functionality.

you can find a free trial here - http://www.wholetomato.com/